# Copy Title by class INSTAGRAM, selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, instagram

Guys i want copy nick of followers Instagram.

This is my code but don't work:

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver')

"GO INSTAGRAM PAGE FOR LOGIN"

browser.get('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?hl=it')

sleep(2)

"ID AND PASSWORD"

elem = browser.find_element_by_name("username").send_keys('test')

elem = browser.find_element_by_name("password").send_keys('pswtest')

"CLICK BUTTON AND OPEN INSTAGRAM"
sleep(5)
good_elem = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/article/div/div[1]/div/form/span/button').click()

sleep(5)

browser.get("https://www.instagram.com")

sleep(2)

browser.get("https://www.instagram.com/test/")
sleep(10)

copy = browser.find_element_by_class_name('FPmhX notranslate zsYNt').Text
```

This is Instagram:

```
"
a class="FPmhX notranslate zsYNt " title="s_yagami_" href="/s_yagami_/">s_yagami_ a"
```

I want copy title, help me.

Comment: Guys help me please.

Comment: What do you mean does not work? Can you be more specific and describe what you expect and what actually happens?

Comment: Don't copy nothing

Comment: Do you mean that the variable copy is `None`? Or is it an empty string? I see a potential problem with the last line, even though I believe that it should have raised an exception: AFAIK `find_element_by_class_name` doesn't work with a set of classes (this that are separated by spaces), but only with a single class name)

Answer (score 1):

`title` is an attribute of `<a>` tag, so can try:

```
copy = browser.find_element_by_class_name('FPmhX notranslate zsYNt')
copy.get_attribute("title")
```

Comment: Don't work. But all title have same class, i want copy multiple title.